# Critical points of $f(x)=\int_{x}^{x^2} e^{-{t^2}}dt$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I understand that you need to take derivative of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ needs to be either equal to zero or undefined to find $f(x)$'s critical points. However what happens if $f(x)$ is given as an integral as in the title?

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x}^{x^2} e^{-{t^2}}dt = F'(x^2)2x - F'(x)$$
$$F'(x^2)2x - F'(x)= 2xe^{-{x^4}} - e^{-{x^2}}$$

Is the calculation above correct for the question on the title?

What should I do next? Thank you.

Comment: Your progess so far has been correct, but [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+exp%28x%5E4+-+x%5E2%29+-+2x%2C+0+%3C+x+%3C+1.5) suggests that the derived equation has no roots simple to write down.

Comment: @Saad, how is the WA plot related to this question?

Comment: Mostafa, I was writing my answer and I didn't see the answer of @Saad, which is equivalent to mine. The WA plot is related to the question because it shows you where the two solutions of the equation $f'(x)=0$ are (the $x$ values that solve the equation are the points in which the curve crosses the x-axis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ is well defined for every value of $x$, and 
$$
f'(x) = 2 x e^{-x^4} -  e^{-x^2}
$$
The equation $ 2 x e^{-x^4} -  e^{-x^2}=0 $ is equivalent to 
$$
 2 x e^{x^2-x^4} = 1
$$
or to any other equivalent form that you can find convenient for carrying out a graphical solution. 
In fact, this cannot be solved with analytical methods but making a plot you discover that  there are two positive solutions for $x \approx 0.5$ and $x \approx 1.3$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. After that point, to be able to draw its graph, I valued x from zero to $\frac{3}{2}$ and got some y values. Consequently, interpreted the y values to say $x_1$ is close to 0.5 and $x_2$ is close to $\frac{3}{2}$.